# Gradle: DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet to File using toString() method has been deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to update the Gradle plug-in of an Android library project. The new version is `0.10.4`. The Gradle wrapper is at `1.10`. The following **warning** appears when I run `./gradlew install` on the project.

```
Converting class com.android.build.gradle.internal.api. \
DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet to File using toString() method has 
been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. 
Please use java.io.File, java.lang.String, java.net.URL, or java.net.URI instead.
```

I am not sure but the marked lines should the cause:

```
// build.gradle

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java // <----
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java // <----
}
```

How can I rewrite the code to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Try the following construction: `project.file(android.sourceSets.main.java)`. Maybe will help help but not sure cause have to possibility to try.

Comment: Same warning. Do you know how I can **output the line number** of the associated line so I am able to identify the exact code source?

Comment: Not even know if it's possible. But You can run the script with `-d` switch (debug). The output is much bigger then but it would be easier to find to cause (I suppose).

Comment: I looked through the whole debug output. There is no indication of where the warning originates from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`android.sourceSets.main.java` doesn't have the type you expect. You're passing it to something that expects a `File[]`, but it actually has the type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet`. If you look at the [API for Android `sourceSets`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) at you'll find that there's a `sourceDirs` method that returns what you want. So set up your tasks like this:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

Comment: sorry for the downvote, brain lock down… was suppose to be an upvote :\