# Gradle 2.1 error Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI [src/main/java, src]

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm having troubles compiling my project with maven, I'm receiving this error :

```
* What went wrong:
Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: [src/main/java, src].
The following types/formats are supported:
  - A String or CharSequence path, e.g 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'
  - A String or CharSequence URI, e.g 'file:/usr/include'
  - A File instance.
  - A URI or URL instance.
```

my build.gradle is the same I used in the past and looks :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion = "21.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName VERSION_NAME
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs 'src'
            res.srcDirs 'res'
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'
}
apply from: "../gradle-local-mvn-push.gradle"
dependencies {
}
```

this happen when I'm trying to build and upload into maven an AAR library

```
../gradlew uploadArchives
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle: DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet to File using toString() method has been deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225557/gradle-defaultandroidsourcedirectoryset-to-file-using-tostring-method-has-bee)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the code of your gradle-local-mvn-push.gradle script ? I have the same problem and it was coming from my maven script.

I solved it by replacing:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java
}
```

to

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from 'src/main/java'
}
```

Comment: This is really bad idea. `android.sourceSets.main.java` can be mapped to any path. Replacing it with a string?

Comment: See the right answer in the duplication comment on the question.